# Tree map equivalent in VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary, data-structures, treemap

I would like to know if there is a build-in tree map object in VBA beside the binary one.

Right now I am using 4 nested Dictionaries (from the scripting DLL),
each one declared in separated classes.

```
Classe A
Private dicA As Dictionary
'can do stuff with dicA
'dicA contains String as Key and Class B object as Value

Classe B

Private dicB As Dictionary
'can do stuff with dicB
''dicB contains String as Key and Class C object as Value

Classe C

Private dicC As Dictionary
'can do stuff with dicB
''dicC contains String as Key and Class D object as Value

Classe D

Private dicD As Dictionary
'can do stuff with dicD
'dicD contains String as Key and String as Value
```

To sum up, Classe D objects are child node from Class C objects, Class C objects are child node of Class B objects, ect...

I would just like to know if there is a better way to get this sort of datastructure in VBA.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to implement trees in VBA without using dictionaries? If so, there is a nice book, "VBA Developer's Hanbook" by Getz and Gilbert (out of print but easily purchased  used through Amazon) which has a chapter devoted to implementing dynamic data structures using classes. The book is a treasure-trove of VBA knowledge and definitely worth picking up (whether or not it turns out to be useful for your specific question).

Comment: My question is if there is already a implement tree object in VBA and if not what is the best way to implement one. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: VBA is a fairly old language and doesn't come equipped with many built-in data structures. Collections can be used somewhat like dynamic arrays and you already know about dictionaries. Other than that, it is pretty much roll your own. You don't need classes to use dictionaries as trees, although I suspect that using dictionaries of dictionaries of dictionaries ... is not the most memory-efficient way to store data.